# How to Override/replace jsdoc properties?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm creating an express route handler and I want to extend the `express.Request` interface to document what the params and query properties should be. I would like the jsdoc's to work in had with VsCode intellisense.

At first, I import the `Request` and `Response` from express.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import('express').Request} Request
 * @typedef {import('express').Response} Response
 */
```

I then create 2 types for the `params` and `query`.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   module: string
 * }} params
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   field: string
 *   skip: number
 *   limit: number
 * }} query
 */
```

As a parameter of my function, I extend the express `Request` and override my `query` and `params`.

```js
/**
 * @param {Request & {params: params, query: query}} req
 * @param {Response} res
 */
async function search(req, res)
```

Here is where my problem arises... I only get intellisense for the `params`, but not for the `query`.

**Screenshot of `req.parmas` intellisense**
[image: Screenshot of req.params intellisense]

**Screenshot of `req.query` intellisense**
[image]

When I hover my mouse over the `req` param I get the following intellisense.

[image: req intellisense]

Am I using the 'extend' feature correctly? How can I extend the `Request` type & get intellisense for both `query` and `params`?

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a bug in an earlier VSCode version.  It's working fine in version 1.69:
[image: Visual Studio Code screen shot]